# Why when I use JsonIdentityInfo, I retrieve my parent's entity data only on the first occurence of the query returned values?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, one called Famille which is the parent entity and the other one called Variante which is the child entity.

I want, when I retreive all my Variantes, to get the corresponding Famille informations (all the fields).

To do that, I use the  @JsonIdentityInfo annotation.

But, unfortunately, the JSON returned by my service only return the Famille informations only for the first occurence of Famille.

Does anybody know how to return Famille informations for each occurence ?

This is my Famille entity :

```
@Table(name="famille")
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Famille implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String nom;
    private String couleur;
    private int position;
    private List<Variante> variantes;

    public Famille(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Famille() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="nom")
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }


    @Column(name="couleur")
    public String getCouleur() {
        return couleur;
    }

    @Column(name="position")
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "famille", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Variante> getVariantes() {
        return variantes;
    }

//I don't show the setters



}
```

And this is my Variante entity :

```
@Table(name="variante")
@Entity
@Data
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Variante implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String nom;
    private Famille famille;
    private List<Affaire> affaires;


    public Variante(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Variante() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="nom")
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_famille")
    //@JsonManagedReference
    public Famille getFamille() {
        return famille;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "variante", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Affaire> getAffaires() {
        return affaires;
    }

    //I don't show the setters
}
```

This is my FamilleRestServices :

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class FamilleRestServices {

    @Autowired
    private FamilleRepository familleRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/listFamilles")
    public List<Famille> listFamilles(){return familleRepository.findAll(Sort.by("Position").ascending());}
}
```

And finally my VarianteRestServices :

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class VarianteRestServices {

    @Autowired
    VarianteRepository varianteRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/listVariantes")
    public List<Variante> listVariantes(){return varianteRepository.findAll();}

    @GetMapping(value = "/listVariantesByFamille/{idFamille}")
    public List<Variante> listVariantesByFamille(@PathVariable(name="idFamille") int idFamille){
        return varianteRepository.findVarianteByIdFamille(idFamille);
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/varianteByAffaire/{idAffaire}")
    public Variante varianteByAffaire(@PathVariable(name="idAffaire") int idAffaire){
        return varianteRepository.findVarianteByIdAffaire(idAffaire);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/listVariantes")
    public Variante save(@RequestBody Variante v){return varianteRepository.save(v);}

}
```

When I go to the adress : "localhost:8080/listVariantes" , this is the JSON that is returned by the page :

```
[
{
id: 1,
nom: "E2",
famille: {
id: 1,
nom: "ARRIEL1",
couleur: "32cd32",
position: 1,
hibernateLazyInitializer: { }
}
},
{
id: 2,
nom: "S1",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 3,
nom: "D",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 4,
nom: "M",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 5,
nom: "C2",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 6,
nom: "K1",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 7,
nom: "B",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 8,
nom: "C",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 9,
nom: "A",
famille: 1
},
{
id: 10,
nom: "C2",
famille: {
id: 2,
nom: "ARRIEL2",
couleur: "2b78e4",
position: 2,
hibernateLazyInitializer: { }
}
},
{
id: 11,
nom: "S2",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 12,
nom: "D",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 13,
nom: "C",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 14,
nom: "S1",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 15,
nom: "C1",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 16,
nom: "B",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 17,
nom: "E",
famille: 2
},
{
id: 18,
nom: "B1",
famille: {
id: 7,
nom: "ARRIUS2",
couleur: "ff9900",
position: 5,
hibernateLazyInitializer: { }
}
},
{
id: 19,
nom: "A",
famille: {
id: 11,
nom: "MAKILA2",
couleur: "999999",
position: 10,
hibernateLazyInitializer: { }
}
}
]
```